# Toggle or Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, show-hide

I need help toggling overlays with multiple divs. I don't want to have a separate function for each one (there's 6 with 6 different overlay popups).  The onclick div will reveal the overlay popup. Help is appreciated!
I need help toggling overlays with multiple divs. I don't want to have a separate function for each one (there's 6 with 6 different overlay popups).  The onclick div will reveal the overlay popup. Help is appreciated!

```js
        function on() {
          document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
        }

        function off() {
          document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
```

```css
    #overlay {
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      z-index: 2;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #text{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: white;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<!-- //DIV  -->
<div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch" onclick="on()">
          <div class="card mb-3">
                <img src="img/ballet.jpg" class="embed-responsive w-100 classpic" alt="...">

                  <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">BALLET</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

<!-- //POPUP  -->
              <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
                <div id="text">
                  <h3>Ballet</h3>
                  <p>Ballet is an artistic dance form performed to music using precise and highly formalized set steps and gestures.
                  Classical ballet, which originated in Renaissance Italy and established its present form during the 19th century,
                  is characterized by light, graceful, fluid movements and the use of pointe shoes.
                  </p>
                  <h4>Shedule:</h4>
                  <p>Ages 4-8: Thursdays • 4PM<br>
                     Ages 9-14: Fridays • 7PM</p>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your approach, namely, when an element has `display:none` it is removed from the html tree and cannot receive a click event. Also, no two elements can share the same `id` attribute and so your function cannot be applied by reference to an id directly.

I've made a working snippet that achieves what I think you are after. There are undoubtedly others that would work but it's quite straight forward and works.

Firstly, arrange each of your alternative `div` pairs (one hidden, one visible) inside a parent div and give it a class name. This has the advantage that, if you size the container div appropriately, the content will not jump about when you swap the hidden div for visible and vice versa. Next, give classes to distinguish the (initially) hidden content from the visible div. Your markup pattern then will be repeats of:

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='main'>my first main content</div>
      <div class='hidden'>my first hidden content </div>
    </div>
```

In the style sheet, set the class display properties:

```
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }

    .main {
      display: block;
    }
```

Then, set up a click event listener in javascript. This will take a `click` event from anywhere on the page.

```
    document.addEventListener('click', event => {

    })
```

inside the event listener, place an `if` block to test whether the click event was received by an element that was inside a div of `.container` class:

```
if (event.target.parentElement.className=='container') {


}
```

- I slightly modified this, see edit note and bottom.

If the click event got that far, the click must have been recieved by the visible div inside that container (since the hidden one cannot receive click events and they are the only two elements present.

So you can go ahead and swap the classes applied to the visible div that received the click:

```
        event.target.classList.add('hidden');
        event.target.classList.remove('main');
```

You now have to do the opposite to the other div in the container class to make that sibling visible. The problem is, you don't know whether the hidden class was the first child, or the second child of the container div. What you do know for sure, is that the other div is a *sibling* of the div you just made invisible.

So we can test to see if there is a next sibling using a conditional:

```
    if (event.target.nextElementSibling) {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('main');
      event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
     }
```

If the hidden div followed the visible one, a `nextElementSibling` will be found and the classes swapped. If no `nextElementSibling` was found, we know the other div had to come *before* the one we already hid.

so, an `else` extension of that `if` block can be added to switch the classes on the `previousElementSibling`:

```
 ...} else {
      event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('main');
      event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
    } // end else;
```

And you're done!

I wanted to explain the logic in detail to make sure you know what's going on, but it's not that complicated.

The advantage of an approach like this is that the single event listener will cope with 1, 2, or 1,000 pairs of divs and none need any special IDs or anything other than an initial class of `.main` or `.hidden` (and that they be grouped inside a `.container` div.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {

  if (event.target.parentElement && event.target.parentElement.className=='container') {
    event.target.classList.add('hidden');
    event.target.classList.remove('main');
    
      if(event.target.nextElementSibling) {
event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('main');
event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
      } else {
event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.add('main');
event.target.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('hidden');
      } // end else;
   
   } // end parentElement if;

}) // end click listener;
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='main'>my first main content</div>
  <div class='hidden'>my first hidden content </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='main'>my second main content</div>
  <div class='hidden'>my second hidden content </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** the conditional to detect whether the parent element of the click event was a `.container` div was modified to check that the event target *has* a parent *AND* that the parent *is* a `.container` div. This prevents an error if a click is received anywhere outside of the `container` div.

** Displaying an Opaque Overlay in Response to Click **

Again, this solution allows the functionality to be applied to limitless div elements without the need for independent ids. Again, two classed `.main` and `.hidden` are used to decide which div has been clicked from a single event listener applied to the `document` rather than to multiple divs.

The basic process of displaying, and then re-hiding the (originally hidden) `.overlay` div is very simple:

```
   if (element.className == 'main') {
     element.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0].classList.remove('hidden');   
   } 

   if (element.className == 'overlay') {
     element.classList.add('hidden');   
   }
```

However, a problem arises because of the use of class names, rather than ids. Namely, when the overlay is displayed, a click on it may be received by a descendent element that does not have the class name `.hidden`. To work properly, every descendent of the overlay div would have to be given the .hidden class and the class swapped applied for ever element inside the .hidden div. This could get very complicated if the div had many child elements (perhaps with their own descendents).

Instead, when a click is received, the target element is inspected to see if it has a relevant class (main or hidden). If it does, the script flows to the simple class switching blocks. If it has no, or a different class name however, a `do-while` loop examined the parent element of the click to see if it was contained in a relevant (main or hidden) class. The loop continues searching up the document tree until either a relevant element is found, or there are no more parent elements to examine.

If a parent is found to have the required class name, a reference to the element is passed onto the class switching block.

```
  do {

    if (element && (element.className == 'overlay' || element.className == 'main')) {
      // foundElementClassName = element.className;
      break;
    } // end if;
    
    if (element.parentElement) {
      element = element.parentElement;
    } else {
      break;
    } 

  } while (element.className != "overlay" || element.className != "main");
```

The following working snippet demonstrates the functionality. In it, three divs (coloured pink) have an associated (initially) hidden overlay div, while a fourth div has no associated overlay and should ignore clicks.

If a click is made on a pink div, it's specific overlay appears. A click anywhere on the overlay dismisses it, regardless of whether the click was received by the overlay div itself, or by a child element or deeper descendent (e.g. clicking on the text of the overlay (which is in a child h2 element still allows the correct `.overlay` div to have its styles switched to hide it again.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let element = event.target;

  do {

    if (element && (element.className == 'overlay' || element.className == 'main')) {
      // foundElementClassName = element.className;
      break;
    } // end if;
    
    if (element.parentElement) {
      element = element.parentElement;
    } else {
      break;
    } 

  } while (element.className != "overlay" || element.className != "main");
  // end do-while loop;


// if a relevant element was found, the element object is stored in element variable;

   if (element.className == 'main') {
     element.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0].classList.remove('hidden');   
   } 

   if (element.className == 'overlay') {
     element.classList.add('hidden');   
   } 

}) // end click event listener;
```

```css
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: pink;
}


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
  padding: 20px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
} 

.other {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1. Content of div 1 </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"><h1>overlay for first pink div</h1> </div>
</div>

<div class="other">
some other content that doesn't have an associated overlay and that should ignore clicks.
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2. Content of div 2.</div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"><h1>overlay for SECOND  pink div</h1> </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. Content of div 3. </div>
<div class="overlay hidden"><h1>overlay for Third pink div</h1> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this today.  The div that is going to show is an overlay - so it's taking up the whole screen.  I found the original approach on w3schools but it was only works for one div and I couldn't find an approach to do this with classes. Thanks for explaining all the steps!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for what I'm doing because it's making the divs replace each other.  The overlay is a lower opacity that pops up full screen.  Thanks for the explanation though, this is good to know!

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you wanted them to replace each other, my misunderstanding of 'toggle'. I'll make an edit to add an overlay, it's actually more simple. If it's closer to what you need and anything is not clear, let me know.

Comment: On second thoughts, it's not quite as simple as I first thought. I'll post when I've got it right.

Comment: Finally made some progess, it took a little tinkering to get specific (as explained in latest edit). Working version added in the last snippet. I noticed when I tested it here that when the little preview window is scrolled, the overlay did not occupy the full screen, but didn't see that when testing in a full browser window.